# Check if label is more than a specific value

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a clock and I want users to be able to select the timezone, but the clock can go over 24 hours which should not be possible, it needs to start over at `00:00`.

This is what I've come up with so far, but I keep getting the error `Input string was not in a correct format.`

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text) > 24)
{
     int test = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text) - 24;
     label1.Text = test.ToString();
}
```

I've tried searching around and the only thing I could come up with is `tryparse` but that doesn't work either

Comment: does your `label1.Text` contains `00:00` when you try to parse it? (or something similar but formatted as `hh:mn`)

Comment: Show us the code that makes your clock actually work...

Comment: label1.Text = (DateTime.Now.Hour  + comboBox1.SelectedIndex - 12 + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second).ToString(); combobox1 contains -12 and up to 12.

Comment: Ok...use the AddHours() method to add to DateTime.Now, then follow that up with a ToString() with your desired format: `int offset = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.AddHours(offset).ToString("h:mm:ss tt");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have an instance of business object that represent your clock entity. And label should display values/properties of this business object.

```
public class Clock
{  

    private int _hour;

    public void Increment()
    {
       if (_hour > 23)
          _hour = 0;
       else
          _hour++;

       // Raise event
    }

    public event EventHandler HourChanged;

    public int Hour { get { return _hour; } }
}
```

Instanciate this class in you windows forms application, sign to event and show Hour property